# Pointer being freed was not allocated (while implementing stack as a linked list)

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

Here's my stack:

```
template <class Type>
struct Node {
    Type value;
    Node* next;
    Node(Type n_value)
        : value(n_value), next(nullptr)
    { }
    static Node<Type>* Add(Node<Type>* head, const Type value) {
        if (!head) { head = new Node<Type>(value); }
        else { head->next = Add (head->next, value); }
        return head;
    }
    static void Remove(Node<Type>* head) {
        if (head->next) { Remove(head->next); }
        else { delete head; }
    }
    static void Empty(Node<Type>* head) {
        if (head->next) { Empty(head->next); }
        delete head;
    }
    static void Display(const Node<Type>* head) {
        std::cout << "\nBEGINNING\n";
        std::function<void(const Node<Type>*)> DisplayElements = [&] (const Node<Type>* head) {
            if (head) {
                std::cout << head->value << std::endl;
                if (head->next) { DisplayElements(head->next); }
            }
        };
        DisplayElements(head);
        std::cout << "\nEND\n";
    }
};
```

With following code:

```
auto beg = Node<int>::Add(nullptr, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { Node<int>::Add(beg, i); }
Node<int>::Display(beg);
Node<int>::Empty(beg);
```

Everything is okay:

```
BEGINNING
0
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
END
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

But when I try to remove something:

```
auto beg = Node<int>::Add(nullptr, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { Node<int>::Add(beg, i); }
Node<int>::Remove(beg);
Node<int>::Remove(beg);
Node<int>::Display(beg);
Node<int>::Empty(beg);
return 0;
```

I get `Pointer being freed was not allocated` on `delete head;` in `Remove`. Why? It's absolutely the same as `Empty` (which erases whole list), except it deletes only last node. `Empty` works fine.

`Empty` is needed to delete whole list (so that we don't get memory leaks), and `Remove` is to remove last element.

Comment: Why are those functions `static`?  It looks like you're not sure whether to create a real encapsulated class, or declare some sort of global / class thing.  If you encapsulated the code into a class, the issue would be easier to debug.

Comment: How does `head` get updated in `Add`? `new` is overwriting a copy of the pointer, not the original pointer. EDIT: nevermind, it returns it, duh.

Comment: `Remove` never sets the new last pointer to `nullptr`, so you'll get double-frees since the second call. And use-after-free too.

Comment: When a call to `delete` is done, it does not automatically set the pointer to null.  You have to structure your code so that you are not processing invalid nodes.

Comment: @Oppen @PaulMcKenzie thanks. Here's what I came with 
`if (head->next->next) { Remove(head->next); }
        else {
            delete head->next;
            head = nullptr;
        }` But it still doesn't work

Comment: You should do `head->next = nullptr`. You should also handle the `head->next` being `nullptr` before you attempt to dereference it.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your results.  Using g++ v9.2.1, on Lubuntu 19.10.  My compiler builds to completion.  The "Everything is okay:" displays correctly, but I do NOT get anything analogous to your "Pointer being freed ..." notice.  Here, the program ends with a segmentation fault after 78,000 lines of '0's.  This maybe suggests a stack overflow, which in turn possibly suggests the Remove()'s don't do what you think they do.

Comment: I now think both Remove and Empty do the same WRONG thing.  "delete head" calls the destructor of the node to which head points.  But if DOES NOT remove (or clear) the pointer in the current node.  So you did not 'unlink' the last nodes ... the link list remains in-tact and invalid in several ways.

Comment: @2785528 you're right, deconstruction of node is wrong.

Comment: Please consider creating dtors for all your classes.  As an example .. try running your (invalid) code after adding "~Node() { cout << "\n  ~  " << value << hex << "  " << next << dec; }"  It appears that empty might be working, but the 2nd remove output is surprising.

Comment: Consider naming class data attributes different than other data.  My practice is to prefix all data attributes with "m_",  such that the Node data becomes m_value and m_next.  IMHO, this makes the code much easier to read.  Code is read much more often than it is written.

Comment: Another use for the ~Node dtor:  I think It makes sense to NOT delete a node until 'next == nullptr'.  This confirms that the node has been disconnected from its tree.  My practice would use assert(nullptr == next), which becomes a handy target for setting a breakpoint.  I have sometimes used a 'friendly' infinite loop:  if (nullptr != next) { std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms) },  This infinite loop allows you to attach the debugger for diagnosing how your code got herre.

Comment: If static works for you, I suppose it is ok.  I consider it odd (like PaulMcKenzie).  My trees are always 2 class types ... 1) a Node_t like yours, and the methods use recursion.  and 2) a Tree_t class. Somewhat less likely to have recursive methods, but it owns "Node_t m_root;".  Generally, only Tree_t can access a node ... with several ways of accomplishing this.   I can have many different Tree_t's in the same app.  Static can sometimes hinder that flexibility.

Comment: @2785528 static functions were temporary (by the way, about recursion: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61921720/13076642 ). Thank you for your tips, going to rewrite my code today!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce your results, so instead of an answer, I am providing a nudge on how you might proceed.

---

I changed the parameter of DisplayElements to 'lhead' (for local head), because the 'head' declaration shadow's the one in the outer scope.  You also have some other shadows ... so I recommend you add `-Wshadow` to your compiler settings.

I also added to your Display() function some diagnostic hex output.

```
  static void Display(const Node<Type>* head)
  {
     std::cout << "\nBEGINNING\n";

     std::function<void(const Node<Type>*)> DisplayElements =
        [&] (const Node<Type>* lhead)
           {
              if (lhead)
              {  //           vvvvvvvvvvvv--diagnostic only
                 std::cout << hex << lhead << "  " << dec
                           << lhead->m_value << std::endl;
                 if (lhead->m_next)
                 {
                    DisplayElements(lhead->m_next);
                 }
              }
           };

     DisplayElements(head);
     std::cout << "\nEND\n";
  }
```

And in addition ... I changed the following.  By avoiding the Empty() and the other couple of lines, the first display will more closely match the second:

```
        auto beg = Node<int>::Add(nullptr, 0);
        {
           for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { Node<int>::Add(beg, i); }
           Node<int>::Display(beg);
//         Node<int>::Empty(beg);
        }

        {
//           auto beg = Node<int>::Add(nullptr, 0);
//           for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { Node<int>::Add(beg, i); }
           Node<int>::Remove(beg);
           Node<int>::Remove(beg);
           Node<int>::Display(beg);
           Node<int>::Empty(beg);
        }
```

Now consider connecting the debugger and setting a break point to inspect what "Remove()" is doing.

Don't be shy about adding more diagnostic cout's.

What I notice is:

a) that the last lines of output are an infinite loop.

b) outputs for values 1..8 are identical to the first,

c) the output for value  9  is missing ... and I suppose should be ... but something about that last Node (perhaps the one with 8?) must be confused.

Comment: Possible analysis:  What Remove() does is 'delete head;'  HOWEVER, this statement does not   a) clear the memory which head->next points to, and b) does not clear the pointer 'head->next' in the CURRENT_NODE  (to break the list link)