# How to handle recursion in member functions?

Tags: c++, class, recursion, singly-linked-list, function-definition

E.g., I have an `empty` function to clear a linked list:

```
void empty(Node* head) {
        if (head->next) { empty(head->next); }
        delete head;
        head = nullptr;
    }
```

But then I created a class for the linked list, so now I don't need to pass the `head` argument:

```
void empty() {
        if (head->next) { empty(head->next); }
        delete head;
        head = nullptr;
    }
```

But `empty(head->next)` line is obviously wrong as `empty` doesn't take any arguments. The idea comes to my mind to create a function inside a function (with lambda), something like this:

```
void empty() {
        std::function<void(Node*)> emptyWrapper = [&] (Node* l_head) {
            if (l_head->next) { emptyWrapper(l_head->next); }
            delete l_head;
            l_head = nullptr;
        };
        emptyWrapper(head);
    }
```

But I'm wondering if there's any better way to do it. Lambdas became kind of idee fixe for me recently.

Comment: "But then I created a class for the linked list, so now I don't need to pass the head argument:" head for your recursive function and your class member isn't the same thing. They only share the name.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe there's no difference between `Node* head; empty(head);` and `MyClass head; head.empty();`.

Comment: There's no good reason to use recursion here. Are you doing it as an exercise?

Comment: Make a private helper function and make `empty()` the interface to the public world.

Comment: If you insist on using recursion, then make your publicly facing function `empty` a wrapper around a recursive function which takes in a parameters. For example `void empty() { empty(head); } … void empty( Node *node ) {…}`

Comment: @ChrisMM but making it with lambda is cleaner?

Comment: Using a while loop is cleaner.

Comment: @ChrisMM it would require an additional variable. Do you mean that recursion is difficult to read?

Comment: `while ( head ) { Node *t = head->next; delete head; head = t; }` … It's effectively what you're already doing, but is actually a bit better … Your version will have UB if `head` is already `nullptr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A general approach is to declare a public member function that in turn calls a private static recursive member function.

Pay attention that the name `empty` sounds confusing. It is better to name the function for example like `clear`.

Here you are

```
#include <functional>

//...

class List
{
public:
    //...
    void clear() 
    {
        clear( head );
    }

private:
    static void clear( Node * &head )
    {
        if ( head )
        {
            delete std::exchange( head, head->next );
            clear( head ); 
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

The same approach can be used without defining an auxiliary static function.

```
void clear()
{
    if ( head )
    {
        delete std::exchange( head, head->next );
        clear();
    }
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
class List
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        T data;
        Node *next;
    } *head = nullptr;

public:
    void push_front( const T &data )
    {
        head = new Node { data, head };
    }

    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const List &list )
    {
        for ( Node *current = list.head; current; current = current->next )
        {
            os << current->data << " -> ";
        }

        return os << "null";
    }

    bool empty() const { return head== nullptr; }

    void clear()
    {
        if ( head )
        {
            delete std::exchange( head, head->next );
            clear();
        }
    }
};

int main() 
{
    List<int> list;

    const int N = 10;

    for ( int i = N; i != 0; )
    {
        list.push_front( i-- );
    }

    std::cout << list << '\n';

    list.clear();

    std::cout << "list is empty " << std::boolalpha << list.empty() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> 10 -> null
list is empty true
```

Comment: `delete std::exchange( head, head->next );` you beat me to it.  Nice!

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward solution is to have a helper function that does the work that your recursive function was doing.

```
class List{
public:
   void empty(){
        if (head) { empty_helper(head); }
        delete head;
        head = nullptr;
    }
private:
// should probably be static to avoid propagating this.

void empty_helper(Node* head) {
        if (head->next) { empty_helper(head->next); }
        delete head;
        head = nullptr;
    }
};
```

Of course other options are available, such as making it non recursive.

In my opinion a lambda is unnecessary in this situation.

Comment: Do lambdas have worse performance than default functions? Excessively using them is a bad practice?

Comment: @AlexeiSavitsky No not at all. They are just a convenient syntax.  They provide means to create a very local name for a one-off function.

Answer (score 1):

Note: as others have mentioned, you don't need to use recursion here. This example assumes you want to or need for some reason you haven't mentioned. This is how you **would** do it using recursion. However, restructuring with a loop is probably what you should do in the long run.

---

You can make a public and private version of the list:

```
class list {
public:
void empty();

//...
private:
void empty(Node* head);
// alternatively, you could make this static instead:
static void empty(Node* head);

//...

}
```

Then you can call the `empty()` that takes a parameter from inside the other `empty()`:

```
void list::empty() {
    if(this->head) {  // check here so ->next won't fail in the helper function.
                      // maybe you should add a check there instead
        empty(this->head);
    }
}
```

---

P.S. you probably shouldn't use the name `head` all over the place like I have done here. This was just a quick example I threw together. But at least you get the general idea this way.